# HTML Link Hoverover Buttons

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, html-table

How can I make these buttons all align left with about a 3px space between them and adjust their own size based on how much text is put into them?

Unfortunately I don't have access to my own CSS (someone charges hundreds for this privilege). I've been trying for hours but just can't figure it out:

```
<br>
<style>
.mylink {
    padding: 10px 35px;
    background-color: #434343; 
    color: #fffFFF; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -.2px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif; 
    border-radius: 5px;    
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%
    }

.mylink:hover  {
    background-color: #ff0000; color: #fffFFF;
}
</style>
<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
        <tr>
                        <td width="0%" style="text-align: left;">
                <a class="mylink" href="http://www.zzz.com/">ZZZ</a>
            </td><td width="0%" style="text-align: left;">
                <a class="mylink" href="http://www.aaa.com/">AAA</a>
</td><td width="0%" style="text-align: left;">
                <a class="mylink" href="http://www.FFF.com/">FFF</a>
            </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that means you **do** have access to the HTML?  Is there a reason why you have a table there?

Comment: There's a hierarchy in terms of what css will be evaluated: inline css > in document css > css in css file. So, if you have access to the HTML file, you actually have *final say* in the css being applied

Comment: Thanks - So what changes do I need to make to the code above?

Comment: off topic: I always wondered where shopping trolleys came from. Now I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your other CSS is working by putting it inline (like you have put it), this should work, though a little hacky (floating cells and rows is ... unusual).  I'd get rid of the table altogether if the effect here is what you want:

```
<style type="text/css">
.mylink {
    padding: 10px 35px;
    background-color: #434343; 
    color: #fffFFF; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -.2px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif; 
    border-radius: 5px;    
    font-size: 12px;
    float:left;
}

.mylink:hover  {
    background-color: #ff0000; color: #fffFFF;
}
tr, td {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
}
</style>
<table>
  <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a class="mylink" href="http://www.zzz.com/">ZZZZZZZZ</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="mylink" href="http://www.aaa.com/">AAA</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="mylink" href="http://www.FFF.com/">FFF</a>
            </td><!-- Remove the extra </td> here. -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What this should look like if it works: https://jsfiddle.net/cmhqr3dg/

Comment: Awesome!  Don't forget to accept the answer if it is correct.  :)

Comment: Will do - Just have to figure out how to do it haha

Comment: There's a little checkmark on the left of each answer (beside the up-vote, down-vote arrows).  If you click it, it will become green, indicating that it is the accepted answer.

Comment: Copy that all done! Sorry one more question - I just put the code into my site and there isn't a space between the buttons, is this possible? I'm looking for about a 3px space

Comment: Sure!  Add this line to your `.mylink` class: `margin-right:3px;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the effect you are going for.

```html
<br>
<style>
.mylink {
padding: 10px 35px;
background-color: #434343; 
color: #fffFFF; 
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: -.2px; 
text-decoration: none; 
font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif; 
border-radius: 5px;    
font-size: 12px;
width: 100%
}

.mylink:hover  {
background-color: #ff0000; color: #fffFFF;
}
td {
float: left;
margin: 0 3px;
}
</style>
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
 <a class="mylink" href="http://www.zzz.com/">ZZZZZZZZZZ</a>
</td>
<td>
 <a class="mylink" href="http://www.aaa.com/">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</a>
</td>
<td>
 <a class="mylink" href="http://www.FFF.com/">FFF</a>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I removed the style tags from the "td" elements and added the following into the "style" tags

```
td {
float: left;
margin: 0 3px;
}
```